# Why Json.encodeToString removed one of the model varable

Tags: android, json-deserialization

I want to use kotlin serializable ```encodeToString()`` for encoding a dataModel but one of the dataModel variables is not encoded

Specific DataModel for encoding:

```
 TripInfo(tripId=73, chunkSize=10485760, isCompleted=0)
```

After encoding:

```
{"tripId":73,"chunkSize":10485760}
```

As you can see isCompleted value is not exist in the encoded result

DataModel:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class TripInfo(
    val tripId: Long? = null,
    val chunkSize: Long = 0,
    val isCompleted: Int = 0,)
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlinx.serialization skip fields with default values. Try to delete them and assign the value explicitly (for me this worked)

Answer (score 0):

To include fields with default values, use the @SerialName annotation with the defaultValue

```
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class TripInfo(
    val tripId: Long? = null,
    val chunkSize: Long = 0,
    @SerialName("isCompleted")
    val isCompleted: Int = 0
)
```